# How to make sub menu span full width of the browser window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want my sub menu to span the full width of the browser window like the below image:

[image]

I am using `Bootstrap`, also my main menu is floated to the right.

I have created a demo on what I have done so far. How do I achieve this result?

http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/oLVVXj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, bootstrap makes you really unflexible. So if you want to use it I suggest to move the submenu out of the menu's elements, because the `width:100%;` is dependent on the parent. So everything that should be wider than the parent, shouldn't be the child of this parent element. In addition `position:absolute` is dependent on the next parent with `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. So there are many things that don't make it easy. To move the submenu would make it a lot easier. There you can just use `width:100%;` and `position:absolute` with `left:0`.

***Alternatively*** to get the submenu out of the flow of the page, you could use `position:fixed`. And `width:100%`. Check out the **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLVVqB)** for this solution. I like the first one more, even if it's more work. However, fixed positioning has some side effects, but maybe it's not important for you.

Comment: Your description is not quite clear. The width of the child element is *only* dependent on the parent element if the parent has `position: fixed, relative or absolute`. If you remove the `position` on the parent element - the child will take the width of the nearest grandparent that has position. Hrrrm... this is not clear as well.

Comment: You're wrong. The ``width`` is dependent on the parent. Even if the element has ``position: static;`` (the default one).

Comment: If a parent element does not have position explicitly set, then a child element with position fixed, will position itself relative to the closest grandparent with position set.

Comment: OK, sorry yes the `width: 100%` that you are talking about you are correct. I was referring to the fact that you can make the actual width wider than the parent - by using `left: x` and `right: x`...

Comment: You can also make it wider by using ``width:120%``. There are many ways. I just wanted to say that it's not a good style to do this. At least this is what I think.
But another fact you were wrong with: position fixed is always dependent of the browsers width. That's what I take advantage of in my alternative solution.

Comment: It's a *perfectly fantastic* style to use that method. There would be hundreds-of-thousands of prior examples of this technique. I don't think I made any such suggestion about position: fixed. The only problem with `position: fixed` of course is if the top menu needs to scroll off the page.

Comment: Shame you deleted your comments above with links - i'm sure someone would found it of use.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment with link even before you answered on it. But here again: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyrrZP . But don't let us spam here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The position absolute child will position with respect to the closest position relative parent, so removing the position relative for main-menu li will solve this issue. Also remove the padding and margin from the body and html.

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
.main-menu li {
  float: left;
}
.main-menu li a {
   display: block;
   background: #c2c2c2;
   padding: 20px;
   color: #337ab7;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-menu-dropdown li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.main-menu-dropdown li a {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="has-dropdown" href="#">Second Item</a>
                <ul class="main-menu-dropdown clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        I need the sub menu to span the width of the browser
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, the width of the submenu is being restricted because it's parent element has `position: relative`.

Once that is removed the submenu becomes full width, however the items are still aligned left.

In the example below I made `.main-menu-dropdown` use `display: flex` and then centered the items within it.

http://codepen.io/adrianlynch/pen/RRddjk

```css
.main-menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: It's not full width, but the width of class ``col-md-12``.

Comment: Yeah, as @ScientiaEtVeritas said this needs to be the full width of the browser. Just like how `.container-fluid` spans the full width. Also I want to try avoid using flex due to browser inconsistencies.

Comment: If that is the case, you can adjust the left/right/width to accomodate it.

Comment: Flex is well supported, and issues are well documented. I don't see any reason not to use it these days.

Comment: I've adjusted the codepen above to accomodate the difference between `col-md-12` and `container`. If it actually will just bleed off left and right, you could adjust it any sufficiently large number  (i.e. -1000em).